# How can I fix this GitHub security alert?

Tags: security, github, package.json

After pushing a new repo to GitHub I got this security alert from GitHub:

[image]

According to GitHub, the effected file is **package-lock.json**.

To fix the issue, I did this:

1. Deleted the package-lock.json from remote repo on GitHub.
2. Found and replace tar versions inside my local package-lock.json to >=4.4.2.
3. Deleted node_modules folder from my local repo.
4. Ran npm install
5. Pushed package-lock.json to remote.

But it didn't help and I still get the same security alert from GitHub.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You should never need to delete or edit your `package-lock.json` manually.  In this case, the file you want to edit is `package.json` (no `-lock`).  Specifically:

1. Open `package.json` in your favorite editor.
2. Find the line for `"tar": "…"`.
3. Replace whatever is in the right-hand string with `">=4.4.2"`.
4. Save the file and run `npm install`.
5. Check in the changes to `package.json` **and** `package-lock.json`.
6. Push to Github.

Comment: Often times the offending dep is not something you declared in the `package.json`. What is the recommended way to fix them?